# Maven Simple Webapp archetype doesn't process jsp pages?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, tomcat

**UPDATE**:  It appears that it is Expression Language (EL) that is not being processed.   Inclusion of scriptlets like `<% System.out.println("Hello"); %>`  do in fact work.  So it looks like (this is a wild guess) it's something that's not happy with the JSP 2.1 api that I'm including as a Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**ORIGINAL**:

This is a remarkably simple problem, but I can't find what's causing it.   Hopefully someone can look at it and say "oh, you forgot the X!"  (Whatever "X" turns out to be.)

I created a web project from the Maven Simple Webapp archetype, which yields a simple project with one JSP page, `index.jsp`,

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<c:set var="myVar" >Some Text Here</c:set>
${myVar}
</body>
</html>
```

When build and run this app in Tomcat, I would expect to get a web page that says

```
Hello World!
Some Text Here
```

but instead I get:

```
Hello World!
${myVar}
```

So, the JSP is not being processed somehow.    I don't get an error, but I also don't get the expected result.

The Tomcat server is installed and working with other apps, so I don't **think** the problem is there.    This app is extremely small and simple, here's the `web.xml`

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Here's the entire `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>myweb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myweb Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <compilerSource>1.6</compilerSource>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>myweb</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${compilerSource}</source>
                    <target>${compilerSource}</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is `<% System.out.println("Hello"); %>` working?

Comment: Nope, I get nothing back from that

Comment: Whoops, yes, that is printing "Hello" in the system console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer turns out to be that the Maven Archetype `maven-archetype-webapp` creates a project that won't work with EL. The Archetype generates a `web.xml` file with this DTD at the top of the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
```

This DTD will not work if you are trying to use Expression Language (EL) because EL was not supported until Servlet 2.4.

I was able to get EL working (under Tomcat 7.0.42) by altering the Maven-generated `web.xml` header to read as follows:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
  metadata-complete="true">
```

**FRUSTRATION**: This does not appear to be very clearly documented anywhere - in searching for the source of this problem, I was led to Oracle's website, to people's blogs, to archives of old email lists - it seems that if things like this can be so painfully frustrating, they should be well documented.   Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<c:set var="myVar" scope="session" value="Some Text Here"/>
<c:out value="${myVar}"/>
</body>
```

Comment: No joy, same result, I get `${myVar}` instead of `Some Text Here`